# Link is adding a margin, even when I try to remove margin

Tags: html, css, whitespace, margin

[image]

The arrow Is a link, and even when I remove the margin, like this: margin:0; it still makes that space. I know it is the link because I removed it to see. Here is the link code:

```html
<a href="#desc" class="bottombutton"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-down" style="font-size:36px;" id="downbtn"></i></a>
```

And here is my CSS:

```css
#downbtn{
  position:relative;
  bottom:45px;
  color:white;
  left:50%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Is there something that I am missing to remove the whitespace?

Comment: does the "white bar" disappear when you remove the link? Margin wont work on an inline element, you would have to make it `display: inline-block;`. In your case I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Yes, when I remove the link the white bar disappears

Comment: When you use translate and bottom on a relative element it still holds its space in the layout (i.e. the white bar). So when you translate it up you're just moving the link around but not the container. Try either matching the background on the to the faded black or use position absolute so that it doesn't take space out of the layout.

Comment: Change the link or the i to position absolute?

Comment: Maybe your footer has a margin top?

Comment: I'd be a lot easier to help with an exaple on codepen or something like that because the issue might be related to dofferent element .  Can You prepare such an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Make the element `absolute`, make it `inline-block` and change the `translate` to `translateX`. Don't forget the `position: relative;` on the parent (you probably already knew).

```css
#downbtn {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 45px;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```